# How can I conditionally render tabs depending on the value of a field of a GROQ query?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui, conditional-rendering, groq

I have a GROQ query where the result is an array of documents, of which one of the fields, "fieldName", can contain "a", "b" or "c". If the array contains any with the value "a" then I want to display a Chakra-UI `<Tab>` for it in the `<TabList>` as well as a `<TabPanel>` in the `<TabPanels>`. If there are none with the value "a", don't display a tab, and repeat this for conditions "b" and "c".

```
// GROQ query

*[slug.current == $slug]{
    array[]->
}
```

```
// GROQ query json response

"result": [
    0:
    "array": [
        0: {...}
        1: {
            "_id": "1"
            "fieldName": "a"
        }
        2: {
            "_id": "2"
            "fieldName": "c"
        }
        3: {...}
        4: {...}
        5: {...}
        ]
    }
]

// This example would return tabs and panels for only a and c
```

I know how to loop through the items conditionally in the example below, but this doesn't help me with the `Tab` items as looping through these would give me repeated tabs.

```
<Tabs>
  <TabList>
    <Tab>A</Tab> // Conditionally render this only if any array items' "fieldName" contains value "a"

    ...

  </TabList>
  <TabPanels>
    <TabPanel>
      {array &&
        array.fieldName.map((panel) => (
          <>{panel.fieldName == "a" ? <>{panel.fieldName}</> : null}</>
        ))}
    </TabPanel>

    ...

  </TabPanels>
</Tabs>
```

Because of the structure of Chakra-UI's tabs I am stumped how I can do this and would appreciate any help. There must be a better way of doing this than the one I am trying?

Comment: What does your GROQ query look like?

Comment: I've added it to question above. It doesn't really reveal much. "fieldName" is just one of the fields for "array" for simplicity.

Comment: If your response contains multiple a and c, you wanna show multiple tabs with a and c?
Your example response is an array and contains many elements.

Comment: If the array contains any items that contain a fieldName value of "a", show a tab and a tab panel for A. But do not display a tab for "a" if none of the items in the array contain a fieldName value of "a". And the rule is the same for a, b, and c.

Comment: @Anthony please check the answer & let me know If i missed something.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see that this had had a response. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a object and use it to check if to show specific tab and tabpanel or not

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  Tabs,
  TabList,
  TabPanels,
  Tab,
  TabPanel,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import './style.css';

const arr = [
  {
    _id: '1',
    fieldName: 'a',
  },
  {
    _id: '2',
  },
  {
    _id: '3',
    fieldName: 'c',
  },
  {
    _id: '4',
    fieldName: 'a',
  },
  {
    _id: '5',
    fieldName: 'c',
  },
  {
    _id: '6',
    fieldName: 'e',
  },
  {
    _id: '7',
  },
  {
    _id: '8',
    fieldName: 'c',
  },
  {
    _id: '9',
    fieldName: 'a',
  },
];

function process(arr) {
  const tabs = {};
  arr.forEach((item, idx) => {
    if (item.fieldName && !tabs[item.fieldName]) {
      tabs[item.fieldName] = idx;
    }
  });
  return tabs;
}

export default function App() {
  const tabs = process(arr);
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Tabs>
        <TabList>
          {tabs['a'] && <Tab>A</Tab>}
          {tabs['b'] && <Tab>B</Tab>}
          {tabs['c'] && <Tab>C</Tab>}
          {tabs['d'] && <Tab>D</Tab>}
          {tabs['e'] && <Tab>E</Tab>}
        </TabList>

        <TabPanels>
          {tabs['a'] && (
            <TabPanel>
              <p>A</p>
            </TabPanel>
          )}
          {tabs['b'] && (
            <TabPanel>
              <p>B</p>
            </TabPanel>
          )}
          {tabs['c'] && (
            <TabPanel>
              <p>C</p>
            </TabPanel>
          )}
          {tabs['d'] && (
            <TabPanel>
              <p>D</p>
            </TabPanel>
          )}
          {tabs['e'] && (
            <TabPanel>
              <p>E</p>
            </TabPanel>
          )}
        </TabPanels>
      </Tabs>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

[`Working Example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mzdmk8)